# why getting arrays with 0 indexes?

Tags: php, codeigniter

after my var_dump, i saw these arrays with the same index. Why is that happening?. how can i make instead of zeros it'll be 0, 1, 2,
3....
Here's my full code, its a very very long code: I have this table in my codeigniter view.

```
                Total       Expected
  Day(s)   |Hours Worked | Total hr/day | Undertime | Overtime
2015-05-01 | 09:00:00    | 09:00:00     | 00:00:00  | 00:00:00
2015-05-05 | 08:32:00    | 09:00:00     | 00:28:00  | 00:00:00  
2015-05-06 | 09:21:00    | 09:00:00     | 00:00:00  | 00:21:00
2015-05-07 | 08:22:00    | 09:00:00     | 00:38:00  | 00:00:00  
2015-05-08 | 06:30:00    | 09:00:00     | 00:30:00  | 00:00:00  
2015-05-09 | 08:42:00    | 09:00:00     | 00:18:00  | 00:00:00  
2015-05-10 | 09:00:00    | 09:00:00     | 00:00:00  | 00:00:00
2015-05-11 | 09:24:00    | 09:00:00     | 00:00:00  | 00:24:00
2015-05-12 | 09:41:00    | 09:00:00     | 00:00:00  | 00:41:00
2015-05-13 | 08:46:00    | 09:00:00     | 00:14:00  | 00:00:00
2015-05-14 | 08:54:00    | 09:00:00     | 00:06:00  | 00:00:00
            ttl: 96:12:00|ttl: 99:00:00 |ttl:       |ttl:
```

In getting the total hours from total_hr/day and total_hours is different from Undertime and Overtime. Because it should be Undertime is the result of (expected_total_hr/day-total_hours_worked), overtime is (total_hours_worked-expected_total_hr/day)

what i want is to get the overall total of undertime and overtime.

```
foreach ($unique_date as $late) 
         {   
    $ttl_hrs_wrked = $late['total_hrs_worked'];
    $expected_hrsAday = $late['expected_hrsAday'];
    $duty  = strtotime($ttl_hrs_wrked);
    $expected = strtotime($xpected_hrsAday);
    $hour  = $expected-$duty; //getting the Undertime
             //$hour  = $duty-$expected -> getting the Overtime                   

    I want to try the array_sum() that's why i tried making $hour as an array. but when i checked. it resulted to:

    $timeArrays = array( date("00:i",$hour ));
    }

    var_dump($timeArrays);

    ?>

    array (size=1)
      0 => string '00:00' (length=5)
    array (size=1)
      0 => string '00:28' (length=5)
    array (size=1)
      0 => string '00:39' (length=5)
    array (size=1)
      0 => string '00:38' (length=5)
    array (size=1)
      0 => string '00:30' (length=5)
    array (size=1)
      0 => string '00:18' (length=5)
    array (size=1)
      0 => string '00:00' (length=5)
    array (size=1)
      0 => string '00:36' (length=5)
    array (size=1)
      0 => string '00:19' (length=5)
    array (size=1)
      0 => string '00:14' (length=5)
    array (size=1)
      0 => string '00:06' (length=5)

I tried doing this: $timeArrays[] = (date("00:i",$hour ));
   but when i var_dump( $timeArrays);
it resulted into this.

array (size=1)
  0 => string '00:00' (length=5)
array (size=2)
  0 => string '00:00' (length=5)
  1 => string '00:28' (length=5)
array (size=3)
  0 => string '00:00' (length=5)
  1 => string '00:28' (length=5)
  2 => string '00:39' (length=5)
array (size=4)
  0 => string '00:00' (length=5)
  1 => string '00:28' (length=5)
  2 => string '00:39' (length=5)
  3 => string '00:38' (length=5)
array (size=5)
  0 => string '00:00' (length=5)
  1 => string '00:28' (length=5)
  2 => string '00:39' (length=5)
  3 => string '00:38' (length=5)
  4 => string '00:30' (length=5)
array (size=6)
  0 => string '00:00' (length=5)
  1 => string '00:28' (length=5)
  2 => string '00:39' (length=5)
  3 => string '00:38' (length=5)
  4 => string '00:30' (length=5)
  5 => string '00:18' (length=5)
array (size=7)
  0 => string '00:00' (length=5)
  1 => string '00:28' (length=5)
  2 => string '00:39' (length=5)
  3 => string '00:38' (length=5)
  4 => string '00:30' (length=5)
  5 => string '00:18' (length=5)
  6 => string '00:00' (length=5)
array (size=8)
  0 => string '00:00' (length=5)
  1 => string '00:28' (length=5)
  2 => string '00:39' (length=5)
  3 => string '00:38' (length=5)
  4 => string '00:30' (length=5)
  5 => string '00:18' (length=5)
  6 => string '00:00' (length=5)
  7 => string '00:36' (length=5)
array (size=9)
  0 => string '00:00' (length=5)
  1 => string '00:28' (length=5)
  2 => string '00:39' (length=5)
  3 => string '00:38' (length=5)
  4 => string '00:30' (length=5)
  5 => string '00:18' (length=5)
  6 => string '00:00' (length=5)
  7 => string '00:36' (length=5)
  8 => string '00:19' (length=5)
array (size=10)
  0 => string '00:00' (length=5)
  1 => string '00:28' (length=5)
  2 => string '00:39' (length=5)
  3 => string '00:38' (length=5)
  4 => string '00:30' (length=5)
  5 => string '00:18' (length=5)
  6 => string '00:00' (length=5)
  7 => string '00:36' (length=5)
  8 => string '00:19' (length=5)
  9 => string '00:14' (length=5)
array (size=11)
  0 => string '00:00' (length=5)
  1 => string '00:28' (length=5)
  2 => string '00:39' (length=5)
  3 => string '00:38' (length=5)
  4 => string '00:30' (length=5)
  5 => string '00:18' (length=5)
  6 => string '00:00' (length=5)
  7 => string '00:36' (length=5)
  8 => string '00:19' (length=5)
  9 => string '00:14' (length=5)
  10 => string '00:06' (length=5)
```

Comment: $timeArrays[] =  date("00:i",$hour );

Comment: Remove the array around this: `$timeArrays = array( date("00:i",$hour ));` And change it to: `$timeArrays[] = date("00:i",$hour );` (But something is telling me, that you don't show us your **real** code here. `$timeArrays = array( date("00:i",$hour ));` this will always overwrite your variable, so it's not possible to get your output!)

Comment: That var_dump cannot show that output.its coming from somewhere else.according the code it must show one result

Comment: Masiorama,  Rizier123 In your answers here's what i tried :   $timeArrays[] = ( date("00:i",$hour ));  echo array_sum(date("H:i",  $timeArrays[] )); but im getting a looped array. 1st, 1 array 2 then 3 then 4 arrays until it displays all arrays

Answer (score 1):

It was happening because of the `array`. The array is storing the the value with index `0`. Remove the array and store it in the `$timeArrays[]`. Try this -

```
$timeArrays[] = date("00:i",$hour);
```

Hope the problem will be solved.

Comment: Why should OP "Try this" ? Please add an explanation what you changed  and why you changed it?

Comment: (FYI: ^ This post is an answer not a question); But something is telling me, that OP doesn't show us the real code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30345122/why-getting-arrays-with-0-indexes#comment48783135_30345122

Comment: Might be there are some other codes like printing inside a loop or something.